# вывод одномерного и двумерного массива

Tags: java, массивы

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] vector = new int[1];
    vector[0] = 100;
    System.out.println(vector[0]);
```

выводит 100

```
    int[][] matrix = new int[1][1];
    matrix[0][0] = 200;
    System.out.println(matrix[0][0]);
}
```

Почему выводит 200 а не 200200?

Comment: А почему должно быть 200200? Элемент ``matrix[0][0]`` содержит число 200, оно и выводится.

Comment: Так радоваться надо - правильно выводит.

Comment: он двумерный .а как число 200 помещается в нем

Comment: один индекс одно число

Comment: два индекса  два числа я так понимаю

Comment: Двумерный массив - таблица. Индексы - номер ячейки (строка и колонка). В одной ячейке одно значение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
matrix[0][0] = 200;
```

Вы присваете не двум элементам массива значение двести, а присваиваете значение 200 первому индексу массива, который является первым индексом внешнего массива. Если еще понятнее - первый индекс - это номер массива, с которым в работаете, второй индекс - индекс в массиве, который находится в том массиве, который вы указали первым индексом. Так вы в вашем примере вы обращаетесь к нулевому индексу внутреннего массива нулевого внешнего.

Comment: значит первй индекс это 200 а второй по умолчанию 0 ? тогда почему не выводит  0

Comment: Вы выводите только первый индекс внутреннего массива. Это 200. Вы не выводите никакого второго значения, чтобы можно было вывести что-то кроме 200. У вас есть массив, который хранит другие массивы, а не числа, по этому числа он не будет выводить в принципе, ни 0 ни чтобы-то другое. Это как написать array.toString(). [0][0] - значит вывести первый элемент первого внутреннего массива, то есть, вывести одно значение, которое в данном примере - 200.

Comment: спасибо дошло////////////